# Is it possible to deploy external libraries in AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My Node.js application depends on an external library for execution. Is it possible to deploy the Node.js application along with the external library in AWS Lambda? If it is possible, then please suggest which mechanism should be used to deploy the external library.

Answer (score 11):

It sure is, you just zip up the whole directory and upload that instead of editing in console. [Here's the official docs for this.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html)

To make life a little easier, I personally highly recommend using a framework for writing lambdas. I use [Apex](http://apex.run), but I've heard great things about [Serverless](https://serverless.com/).

With Apex, after you get setup you would just use `apex deploy` which will do all the zipping and such for you.

Comment: Yeah I use serverless it's really rather good, also I've yet to try this out but it looks really good(Atlassian Localstack) https://github.com/atlassian/localstack